# Progress bar pass float argument

Tags: android

I tried to build a progress bar in android, as you know progress bar get int for progress, but I need to pass float to progress bar, what can I do?

```
private Runnable myThread = new Runnable(){  
    @Override
    public void run() {
                mypb = mypb + 100 / time;
                pb.setProgress(mypb);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> setProgress() doesn't have float argument. So you can not set float value.

but you can cast your float value to int by-

```
 pb.setProgress((int)mypb);
```

Answer (score 21):

You probably have it solved by now, but my workaround to this is multiplying by 10 or 100, depending on the number of decimals.

If your value is, 30.59 and your max is 100, then just multiply both values by 100. Which will give you 3059 and 10000.

Answer (score 0):

You can math out how many updates your progress will have by dividing the total in as many parts as you want to update, then get the reminder of loop index and first variable.

```
if ((i % (earthquakes.length()/20)) == 0) {
progCount = (int) ((i / (float) earthquakes.length()) * 100);
publishProgress();
}
```

In this case, I divided length by 20 and it will update every 5%. Of course you need to multiply at the end by 100 and cast int to have a int between 0 and 99. If you wish, add one to make it 1 to 100.